# Bug in VC++ 2015 IDE when debugging?

Tags: c++, user-interface, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I am just observing an apparent error when debugging a C++ code in Visual Studio 2015 IDE. Is it a known problem?

When making steps (F10), the yellow arrow on the left that should point to the current place that is to be executed in the next step seems to be misplaced few lines upper. See the image
[image: misplaced debugging pointer]

Notice the red value in the Locals panel that shows that the `sqlStatement` variable just changed. That means that the yellow arrow should actually be placed at the `ret = SqlExecDirect(...`. When following the debug steps in the source code carefully, I can see that indeed the current point is a bit farther than where the yellow arrow points.

The information about the VS--captured from the About dialog--follows:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055

Installed Version: Professional

Visual Basic 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA650
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA650
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA650
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   1.0
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11106.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.30624.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Common Azure Tools   1.5
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

DevExpress.DeploymentTool   1.0
A useful tool for deploying DevExpress assemblies.

KofePackagePackage Extension   1.0
KofePackagePackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

NuGet Package Manager   3.3.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015 ENU   14.0.23025
Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015 ENU

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

Python Tools for Visual Studio   2.2.31105.00
Python Tools for Visual Studio provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, Interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.

Python Tools for Visual Studio - Django Integration   2.2.31105.00
Provides templates and integration for the Django web framework.

Python Tools for Visual Studio - Profiling Support   2.2.31105.00
Profiling support for Python projects.

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.50717.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript   1.7.4.0
TypeScript for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development   1.0
Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development

Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0
This package contains the necessary Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.

XtraReports package   1.0
XtraReports package
```

Comment: I'm sure you've thought of this, but I have seen this behaviour sometimes when I've attached the debugger to out-of-date binaries, i.e. I've made source code changes which are not compiled into the binaries I'm attempting to debug.

Comment: I have recompiled it before debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dare to answer my own question as it is unlikely that someone would found it without having the exact sources and the situation.

I use also Git as the VCS (installed from the official http://git-scm.com/). I also have set the Git `core.autocrlf=false`. It could be the case that I have touched the sources with another editor (Notepad++) or something...

When closing the solution, closing the Visual Studio, starting Visual Studio again, and opening the project, the Visual Studio warned about mixing line endings (CR LF). When the suggested fix was confirmed, the problem disappeared.

It makes sense if the code that sets the yellow arrow counts the lines differently than the rest of the editor (the editor window is more forgiving when the line endings are mixed).

As Visual Studio has its own Git support, the things could be confused during the cooperation of various software layers.